# Python 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python

I'm making something in Python where it scrapes the data off of https://what-to-code.com/random and prints it to the console. Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

wtcRandom = "https://what-to-code.com/random"
html = requests.get(wtcRandom).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for data in soup.find_all(('div', {'class': 'card-content'}).find("p").text):
    print(data.get_text())
```

The error I'm getting is: `python AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find'`

The website has nested divs and then a paragraph tag which is the thing I need (not sure if that matters)

Comment: `find_all()` returns a list of elements. A list does not support `.find()`. See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all and https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find for more details. As you are getting a tuple, you might want to investigate this in addition.

Answer (score 0):

Usually cards are generated dynamically with JS, so BS won't see them in the DOM. Does the html variable actually contains the 'card-content' class? Try to print it out and search for it.

If that's the case you might want to use something like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) that loads the JavaScript and you will be able to see the cards.